# Flutter variable initialization fails

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I declared a late variable - `late String uid;` as shown and tried to initialize it later on. This is my full code

```
late String uid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchUserID();
    super.initState();
  }

  void fetchUserID() async {
    final user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
    uid = user.userId;
  }
```

but I get `LateInitializationError: The field uid has not been initialized`. I'm not really certain what's wrong there and not sure what to do to fix that. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: variable initialisation is ok - the error comes from somewhere else when you are trying to use not initialized `uid` variable - check the stacktrace and you will know the exact location in your code

Comment: I know where but could I ask why I get that error if the variable is initialized? I've used it inside the build  method

Comment: no, it is not initialized yet, add two `print` statements just before and after the line `uid = user.userId;` and one another `print` just before you want to access `uid` inside `build` method - check https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await to find out why this happens

Comment: The `build` method won't wait for your future to complete, it may run before the initialization of `uid` is done. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77575316/13625293

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nullable type and check if the variable is null before using it.

```
String? uid;

@override
void initState() {
  fetchUserID();
  super.initState();
}

void fetchUserID() async {
  final user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
  setState(() {
    uid = user.userId;
  });
}
```

AlSO // Check if uid is null before using it.

Answer (score 0):

In dart, you can't use late for Future method just like that. Because the Future method can return error if something bad happened, meanwhile late variable requires exact value as its type at that time of moment.

```
late String? uid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchUserID().then((value) { uid = value; setState(() {}); });
    super.initState();
  }

 Future<String> fetchUserID() async {
    final user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
    return user.userId;
  }
```

Then you can do the check in build method by using if statement

```
if (uid == null) return SizedBox();
return SomeWidgetHere();
```

Comment: Thank ou I'm trying this right now. Thanks for the information as well